# SwiftMailer keeps giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, email, smtp, web-hosting

My web host has PHP's mail function disabled. I'd like to have a contact form on my site, but I've always used PHP's mail function in the past. To get around the ban my host suggested I use local SMTP instead. All day I've been trying phpmailer and Swiftmailer without much success. I know I'm using the appropriate log in information - but each time I try to send a test message I receive a 500 error. All I want is a simple contact form! I have to be missing something. Please help! SwiftMailer test code is written below:

```
**Index.Html**
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test form to email</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<h1> SwiftMail Test </h1>
<form action="newnew.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</p>


</body>
</html>

**newnew.php**
```

```
include_once "swift_required.php";

$subject = 'Hello!';
$from = array('mywebmail@webmail.com' =>'My Name');
$to = array(
 'myemail@gmail.com'  => 'My Name'
);


$html = "This is a test Email!";
$subject = "Test Subject";

$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 465);
$transport->setUsername('mywebmail@webmail.com');
$transport->setPassword('mypassword');

$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($to);

if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
 echo 'Message successfully sent!';
} else {
 echo "There was an error:\n";
 print_r($failures);
}
```

Comment: localhost seems unlikley if you cant use mail()

Comment: Support at my webhost told me this "The local SMTP is already in place, you would just connect to 'localhost' using the username and password of an email account you've created."

Comment: then why did they disable mail()?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a beginner - not sure I understand the question. I'm just going by what they said.

Comment: Error 500 means some server-side error. Check the logs to get the exact problem. Then post it here, if you still don't know how to solve it.